# Switch stops displaying after adding Thumb/Track drawables

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout

I added switch, I wanted to change its color, so i added following in drawables.

**Thumb.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/black" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@color/tabAccessoryButtonSelected" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@color/tabAccessoryButtonSelected" />

</selector>
```

**Track.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@color/tabAccessoryButtonSelected" />

</selector>
```

**Layout.xml**

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:text="@string/notification_settings"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
    android:track="@drawable/track"
    />
```

As soon as i added this, switch has stopped displaying in the layout, the text is still there, but the Switch tool is not there.

If i remove `Thumb.xml` and `Track.xml` it starts displaying switch.

Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have modify it now try my solution below.

**Layout.xml**

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:text="@string/notification_settings"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
    android:track="@drawable/track"
    />
```

**track.xml**

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/color_thumb" />  
        <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/gray_track" />  
    </selector>
```

**thumb.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/gray_track" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/color_thumb" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/color_thumb" />
    <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/gray_track" />
</selector>
```

**color_thumb.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="40dp"  />
    <gradient android:height="40dp" android:startColor="@color/tabAccessoryButtonSelected"" android:endColor="@color/tabAccessoryButtonSelected""/>
</shape>
```

**gray_track.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="40dp"  />
    <gradient android:height="40dp" android:startColor="@color/tabAccessoryButtonSelected" android:endColor="@color/tabAccessoryButtonSelected"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks :) , But still its not displaying `Swtich` in layout. If i just remove `android:thumb` from layout, it starts displaying switch.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I had the same problem today and the issue seemed to be that the thumb drawable needs a fixed size. The track size seems to adjust itself to the size of the thumb so a thumb with no indicated size won't display and because of this the track won't display either.

If you add an actual xml drawable as a thumb and not just a color you can add a size element to it:

**switch_thumb.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorSwitchThumb" />

    <corners android:radius="@dimen/switch_corner_radius"/>

    <size android:height="10dp" android:width="10dp"/>

</shape>
```